# how to send json object to web service using post request in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic2 and i want to send request to web server when user register with new account, the data which will sent to web service must be like that:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "action": "REGISTRATION",
    "lang": "AR"
  },
  "Request": {
    "user_name": "user",
    "email": "user@yahoo.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "mobile": "12345678"
  }
}
```

this is the service =>

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response     ,Headers } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

public users: any;

userUrl = "safe-pay.co/safepay/public/api/user"

constructor(public http: Http) {

}

signup() {
    var jsonData = {"Data":{
            "action": "REGISTRATION",
            "lang": "AR"
        },
        "Request": {
            "user_name":"user",
            "email":"user@yahoo.com",
            "password":"123456",
            "mobile":"12345678"
        }
    }

    return this.http.post(this.userUrl,JSON.stringify(jsonData)).map((response: Response) => response.json()).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
        },
        (err) => console.log("error is "+err+" data is "+jsonData)
    )
  }
 }
```

and when i call this function, i got this error

error is SyntaxError:

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data data is [object Object]

Comment: use `,` in console log instead of `+` to see the contents of the object . `+` will   just concatenate to string..

Comment: when you are posting the data why are you stringifying the data, you should use JSON.parse(jsonData) right as you need to send json data to server

Comment: it is the output when using , in console.log("json data ",jsonData," stringified object ",JSON.stringify(jsonData)) => output json data  Object { Data: Object, Request: Object }  stringified object  {"Data":{"action":"REGISTRATION","lang":"AR"},"Request":{"user_name":"user","email":"user@yahoo.com","password":"123456","mobile":"12345678"}}

Comment: it gives me error when using JSON.parse(jsonData) because jsonData is not a string